# How to call dependent APIs on button click using react query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I need to call 2 APIs on button click where second query is depend on first query, I need to pass data from first query to second query, I can achieve this using javascript function but I want to use "react-query" because I am sure there will be less code and I will get "isFetching" and "data", below is working javascript function

```
const addGuestCart = () => {
    let getCartKey = new FormData();
    getCartKey.append('lang', 's001');
    let config1 = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'first api_url',
      data: getCartKey,
    };
    axios(config1)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        let guestCart = new FormData();
        guestCart.append('qty', '1');
        guestCart.append('lang', 's001');
        guestCart.append('sku', sku);
        guestCart.append('opid1', '0');
        guestCart.append('opvalue1', '0');
        guestCart.append('opid2', '0');
        guestCart.append('opvalue2', '0');
        guestCart.append('productid', id);
        guestCart.append('cartid', data.cartid);
        guestCart.append('key', data.key);

        let config2 = {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'second api_url',
          data: guestCart,
        };
        axios(config2).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          // return res;
        });
      });
  };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an example for this use case in the docs: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

```js
// Get the user
 const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
 
 const userId = user?.id
 
 // Then get the user's projects
 const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
 
 // isIdle will be `true` until `enabled` is true and the query begins to fetch.
 // It will then go to the `isLoading` stage and hopefully the `isSuccess` stage :)
```